# Vector assigned the standard deviation of matrix columns is changing its value (RcppArmadillo)

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm working on a RcppArma Package and I am centering and standardizing a design matrix for a boosting algorithm, this is the code stripped down:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List centering(arma::mat & X) {

   int p = X.n_cols;

   rowvec meanx(p);
   rowvec sigmax(p);

    meanx=mean(X,0);
    sigmax=stddev(X,0);

    for(int j=0;j<p;j++)
    {
      X.col(j)=X.col(j)-meanx(j);
      X.col(j)=X.col(j)/sigmax(j);
    }

  return List::create(Named("sigma") = sigmax, Named("X") = X);
}
```

The centering works fine, but after the centering the vector "sigmax" has all values equal "1", so the vector somehow updated itself to the new standard deviation of the centered matrix X, without getting reassigned. I need the original values to back transform the coefficients. Why does it do this? How can I avoid this?

I tested the function in R with following code:

```
set.seed(42)    
X <- replicate(10, rnorm(100, 5, 3))
res <- centering(X)
res <- centering(X)
```

The problem appears when i call it a second time. The first time works.

Comment: Hi Oliver, and welcome to SO!  Please consider taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn about _minimally verifiable reproducible examples_.  They make it *much* easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for your answer and your help, I read it and stripped the problem down to a new question. I hope this helps you to understand what my problem is.

Comment: Yes, looks better.  I'm tied up right now and can't work on this -- but can you maybe also add two lines in R for some mock data to call it?

Comment: Okay! Basically i called it directly in RStudio and just generated a random 10x100 X~(5,3).

Comment: So write down that line, and a `set.seed(X)` call for some `X` and, _presto_, we're reproducible.

Comment: Okay, sorry, i'm really new to R and Rcpp. I was able to analyse the problem a bit more: It only happens if i call the function two times with the same data X. If i create new data X it doesn't appear, even when using the same seed.

Comment: That problem is addressed in the Rcpp FAQ and other places.  In essence, you are passing a pointer and _the incoming data can get altered if you assign to it_.  It's due to how R offers us this interface.  Look into `Rcpp::clone()` to create distinct (local) copies if that is what you need.  Also: your example is not minimal. Do we need a list of length 10?  Do we need 500 rows on the matrix?

Comment: Dirk, thank you, this solves my problem. I'll try to improve on making my examples more minimal in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: Do not use a reference (`&`) alongside the parameter `X` in the function definition. This activates RcppArmadillo's use of [an advanced constructor for `arma::mat`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_mat) that re-uses the *R* object memory (c.f. [`include/RcppArmadilloWrap.h`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/RcppArmadilloWrap.h))

So, to fix this issue go from:

```cpp
List centering_reuse_memory(arma::mat & X) {
                                    # ^ reference/reuse
  # Routine given in OP
}
```

To:

```cpp
List centering_new_memory(arma::mat X) {
                                 # ^ Direct copy

  # Routine given in OP
}
```

#### Understanding the sharing...

Let's take a look at how the object changes.

```r
# Create the original object
set.seed(42)    
X <- replicate(3, rnorm(5, 5, 3))

# Create a duplicate object not sharing memory with X
set.seed(42)    
X_clone <- replicate(3, rnorm(5, 5, 3))

# View object
X
#         [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
# [1,] 9.112875  4.681626  8.9146090
# [2,] 3.305905  9.534566 11.8599362
# [3,] 6.089385  4.716023  0.8334179
# [4,] 6.898588 11.055271  4.1636337
# [5,] 6.212805  4.811858  4.6000360

# Check equality
all.equal(X, X_clone)
# [1] TRUE
```

Now, running the function with the parameter pass of `arma::mat & X`

```r
res <- centering_reuse_memory(X)

# Verify results are the same.
all.equal(X, X_clone)
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 8.387859"

# Check X manually to see what changed... 
X
#             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  1.34167459 -0.7368308  0.6566715
# [2,] -1.45185917  0.8327104  1.3376293
# [3,] -0.11282266 -0.7257062 -1.2116948
# [4,]  0.27645691  1.3245379 -0.4417510
# [5,] -0.05344967 -0.6947113 -0.3408550
```

Why is there a difference? Well, by using references the modifications in the *C++* function propagated back to the `X` variable residing in *R* that *matches* the object stored at `res$X`.

```r
# Verify R's X matches the saved C++ routine X modification
all.equal(X, res$X)
# [1] TRUE
```